# REST project error (Tomcat: HTTP ERROR 404)

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jakarta-ee, webservice-client

I just begin to learn java rest service. I follow some of the website to build a Rest service but it seems like it keeps gave me the same error :'(.

Trust me! I have tried to search stackoverflow and other forum for solutions but it seems like it doesn't work for me. The error keeps coming back to me.

**Project:**
I made Dynamic Web Project in version 4.9 and Tomcat 8.5 in eclipse. Then I copy all the jars to WEB-INF/lib

Please check below screenshots for project details:

**Server Details:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHzrc.png)

**Project Details:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgUCt.png)

**WEB Content:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I66jU.png)

**META-INF**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAWwW.png)

**Code Details:**

```
package com.firstproject;

import javax.ws.rs.*;


@Path("/")
public class Scoreservice {


    private static int WIN,LOSSES,TIES;


    @GET
    @Path("/score")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getScore() {
        String pattern =  "{ \"wins\":\"%s\", \"losses\":\"%s\", \"ties\": \"%s\"}";
            return String.format(pattern, WIN, LOSSES, TIES);
    }


    @PUT
    @Path("/score")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String update(@QueryParam("WIN") int wins, 
                            @QueryParam("LOSSES") int losses, 
                            @QueryParam("TIES")   int ties) {
       Scoreservice.WIN   = wins;
       Scoreservice.TIES   = ties;
       Scoreservice.LOSSES = losses;
       String pattern = 
          "{ \"wins\":\"%s\", \"losses\":\"%s\", \"ties\": \"%s\"}";
       return String.format(pattern, WIN, LOSSES, TIES);   
    }



    @POST @Path("/scores/wins")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public int increaseWin() {
        return ++WIN;   
    }


    @POST @Path("/scores/losses")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public int increaseLosses() {
        return ++LOSSES;    
    }


    @POST @Path("/scores/ties")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public int increaseTies() {
        return ++TIES;  
    }

    //GET METHOD

    @GET @Path("/scores/wins")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public int getWin() {
        return WIN; 

    }

    @GET @Path("/scores/losses")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public int getLosses() {
        return LOSSES;  
        }


    @GET @Path("/scores/ties")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public int getTies() {
        return TIES;    
        }

}
```

**Problems:**

Upon completion of code, I tried to run it on server but it keeps gave me the same result which is the Http 404 erros (as per attached link below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0922X.png)

**Console log:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddbbp.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M75Li.png)

I do not know what's wrong with the project and I swear that I really tried to search for results before I came here to ask for this question. Hope you guys help me out and Thanks!

Comment: what URL are you trying to connect to?  Are you `GET`ing or `POST`ing?

Comment: Can you  attach the console log in Eclipse when starting tomcat server?

Comment: Connecting to URL: "http://localhost:8080/JavaRest/score" and is GET ing @ScaryWombat

Comment: below tomcat / webapps is there a directory containing your code named `JavaRest` ?

Comment: Hi @htpvl, I have attached the console log. Take note that i have changed the port number as the port I used earlier is occupied. I have changed the server details picture (as per attached in "Server Details")

Comment: @ScaryWombat, yes the directory containing code named is JavaRest (As per attached in "Server Details")

Comment: Your tomcat started but your webapp is not really deployed yet.

Comment: @htpvl May I know is there how to deploy in this situation?

Comment: @Stephen, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your Console log, it seems that your webapp is not deployed yet even your tomcat is started in Eclipse.

You can modify your Tomcat configuration in Eclipse by switching sever location to "Use tomcat installation"(check attached image). Currently, that option is disabled, you can remove your app from tomcat server, stop and clean tomcat server. Then that option will be re-enabled.

Give a try and tell me what is going on.

[image: Switching tomcat server location]

Comment: Hi htpvl, I have attached the picture as for your reference. The error remained unchanged.

Comment: @Stephen, follow this video, quite similar to my answer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orctlc_F5Y0

Comment: Hi htpvl, I have attached the screenshot in your post for your reference. I followed the youtube link you provided but it remained unchanged. The error still appear.